# I have install the wordpress site in subdirectory. Only the index(which is set to be front page ) page is working.

Tags: php, wordpress, windows-server-2008, subdirectory

Rest of page is not working even doesn't show the error.only index page show the current subdirectory header and footer. rest of page show the header and footer from base(parent) site (normal php site direct content).

1. Header and footer only working front page
2. all subpage and categories page not show the content only show the header and footer from parent site

I have changed the htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

change your permalinks in WP dashboard

https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen

Comment: Thx for you reply Yes it is working but only in "Plain" option.but i need it in "Post name"   http://www.example.com/blog/?cat=2  but i want the url like this http://www.example.com/blog/category/test/